# InverseFunction Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I got this answer as a result in a DSolve procedure in Mathematica. I try to translate it into standard mathematical notation, but I like to be sure.

Gamma is a parameter and C[1] and C[2] are constants of integration.

I appreciate any help with this:

```
    pc[t] ->C[1]/(\[Gamma]^2 + 
  InverseFunction[(
     Sqrt[C[1]/(\[Gamma]^2 + #1^2)^2] (\[Gamma] #1 + 
        ArcTan[#1/\[Gamma]] (\[Gamma]^2 + #1^2)))/(2 \[Gamma]^3) &][-(
     t/(2 \[Gamma])) + C[2]]^2)^2




   b[t] -> InverseFunction[(
    Sqrt[C[1]/(\[Gamma]^2 + #1^2)^2] (\[Gamma] #1 + 
       ArcTan[#1/\[Gamma]] (\[Gamma]^2 + #1^2)))/(2 \[Gamma]^3) &][-(
    t/(2 \[Gamma])) + C[2]]
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I just want to know how to write this output in standard mathematical notation....

Answer (score 0):

Mathematical notation is a great area of science, perhaps [Mathematical notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_notation).
You wish to write the formula in [MathML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML) type notation. This is a feature of Mathematica itself. Have a look at this [Tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/XML/tutorial/MathML.html).

You have #1 and the & symbol in your solution. There might be problems to put this into MathML at all.

& says in Mathematice it is a pure function. You have to annotate that in mathematics language. #1 is a special variable symbol for which Mathmetica solver do not use the symbol t. t is the variable for which the function is evaluated. #1 remains an internal variable. Try to get ride of it. A possible way is explain [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/SolveADifferentialEquation.html). Use =,/, and Part to define a function using : ...

After simplification the solution might be easy to be converted into MathML. MathMl ist the digital version of commense mathematics language. Take care to specialize the contants. If they are real complex and the equation where they get evaluated.